# Opencv average filter gives different output than Matlab average filter

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

The following OpenCV code is written to serve as a diagnostic to compare average filter implementation in Matlab and OpenCV. 
The OpenCV code is

```
Mat P(Size(5,5),CV_64FC1,Scalar(0));

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)
        P.at<double>(i,j) = i;
}


cout<<"Original Matrix is :"<<endl;
cout<<P<<endl;

Mat averageFilter(2,2,CV_64FC1,Scalar(0)),U;
averageFilter = cv::Scalar::all(1.0/(2*2));


filter2D(P, U, -1 , averageFilter, Point( -1, -1 ), 0, BORDER_REPLICATE );
cout<<"Filtered Matrix is :"<<endl;
cout<<U<<endl;
```

The output is

```
Original Matrix is :
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2;
  3, 3, 3, 3, 3;
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
Filtered Matrix is :
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5;
  1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5;
  2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5;
  3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5]
```

Matlab code to replicate the same operation is :

```
ma = [0 0 0 0 0;1 1 1 1 1;2 2 2 2 2;3 3 3 3 3;4 4 4 4 4];
MEANF = fspecial('average',[2 2]);
U = imfilter(ma, MEANF, 'replicate');
```

The output is

```
U =

    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000
    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000
    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000
    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000
```

What is the reason for discrepancy between the two outputs ?

Answer (score 2):

The difference you are seeing is due to the different choice of where the origin within the even-sized filter is. For odd-sized kernels, software tends to be consistent and pick the middle pixel as the origin. But for even-sized kernels there are two choices that make equal sense.

I can replicate the OpenCV output in MATLAB by changing the origin of the filter:

```
ma = repmat((0:4).',1,5);
filt = zeros(3);
filt(2:3,2:3) = 1/4;
U = imfilter(ma,filt,'replicate')
filt = rot90(filt,2);
V = imfilter(ma,filt,'replicate')
```

This gives me the same `U` as you had:

```
U =
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000
    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000
    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000
    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000    4.0000
```

And the `V` is what you saw in OpenCV:

```
V =
         0         0         0         0         0
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000    1.5000
    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000    2.5000
    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000    3.5000
```

More instructive is creating an input that is all zeros except for one value in the middle:

```
ma = zeros(5);
ma(3,3) = 1;
filt = zeros(3);
filt(2:3,2:3) = 1/4;
U = imfilter(ma,filt,'replicate')
filt = rot90(filt,2);
V = imfilter(ma,filt,'replicate')
```

Now I see:

```
U =
         0         0         0         0         0
         0    0.2500    0.2500         0         0
         0    0.2500    0.2500         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0

V =
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0    0.2500    0.2500         0
         0         0    0.2500    0.2500         0
         0         0         0         0         0
```

Here it is clear that the kernel was shifted by one pixel.
Again, with `fspecial('average',[2 2])` you'd get the result of `U`, and if you replicate this in OpenCV you'll see an output like `V`.